Get Documents from a List using Graph API
With the SharePoint REST API, there was the /files endpoint that did a recursive search and gave you all the files from a List. Is there anything like that with the Graph API? I've been looking and have not found anything like that.
I've tried a couple of ways:
/items?$isDocument=true

/items?$filter=isDocument eq true

/items?$filter=contentType.name eq 'Document'


You can filter list items by ContentType field
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?$filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Document'

But the request requires the header Prefer with the value HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly
The second option is to use the Graph search API to search for list items and reduce the search to a specific document library specifying by URL
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "path:\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/{document_library_name}\" ContentTypeId:0x0101*"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Content type ID uniquely identify the content type

I tried this and it still returned folders and whatnot. Also, it does not seem to be recursive either.

@datRedHeadedGuy As an alternative you can use /search/query endpoint, check updated answer

ContentTypeId unfortunately did not work either. Is there a way that the search endpoint works in just the URL? Something like /search/query:"ContentTypeId eq '0x010100BE38F469755C3144B2EE3F212E26FA77'"?

I've tried:
/items?$search='contentType/id:0x010100BE38F469755C3144B2EE3F212E26FA77'
/items?$search='contentType/name:Document'
/items?$filter=contentType/name eq 'Document'
/items?$filter=contentType/id eq '0x010100BE38F469755C3144B2EE3F212E26FA77'
These all return results with mixed content types (Folders and Documents). Nothing I've tried will just give me all the documents only. I'm wondering now if I don't just have to parse them out myself.

@datRedHeadedGuy Search endpoint doesn't work with query parameters. Regarding filtering by contentType/id or contentType/name, I think that the filter is always ignored. Could you try queryString with IsDocument:true Instead of ContentTypeId? "queryString": "path:\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/{document_library_name}\" IsDocument:true"

/items?$search='IsDocument:true' comes back with mixed content (documents and folders) too.

I have requested the /files endpoint functionality of the SharePoint REST API in the Graph API. If you would find that useful as well, give it an up-vote.
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/3192eb2e-325f-ef11-a4e6-000d3a02a3a1

The /lists endpoint in Graph API seems to be a dead-end and a waste of time. If you are also dealing with SharePoint/Teams sites, ignore it. You'll probably need to use the /drives endpoint to work with documents, but there is still no way to get just documents. You'll need to separate documents from folders yourself and drill down into each folder yourself too.
